# passing 2 arrays of different sizes using templates in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

I have the following code

```
template <size_t size_x, size_t size_y>
void product(int (&arr)[size_x][size_y],int (&arr1)[size_x][size_y])
{
   for (int i=0;i<size_x;i++)
   for (int j=0;j<size_y;j++)
   {
     cout << "The size of a1[][] is" << arr[i][j] << endl;
   }


   for (int i=0;i<size_x;i++)
   for (int j=0;j<size_y;j++)
   {
     cout << "The size of a1[][] is" << arr1[i][j] << endl;
   }
}

int main()
{

    int A[2][2] = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }};
    int B[2][2] = { { 0, 5}, { 6, 7 } };

    product(A,B);
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to pass arrays to a function. However  this program works fine if the arrays are of equal dimension. I want to pass arrays with different dimensions. How can I pass an array of 2*2 and 3*2 array to a function?

Comment: `template <size_t size_x, size_t size_y, size_t size_x2, size_t size_y2> void product(int (&arr)[size_x][size_y],int (&arr1)[size_x2][size_y2])`

Comment: To build on the comment by @Eljay you can use default-values for the second pair of template values: `template <size_t size_x, size_t size_y, size_t size_x2 = size_x, size_t size_y2 = size_y> ...`

Comment: And for future questions, please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). What is the problem with passing different value for `size_x` and `size_y`? For a *small* array (say `size_x == 2` and `size_y == 3`) what would the expected and actual output be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I pass an array of 22 and 32 array to a function?

This can be done simply by providing extra template parameters

```
template <size_t size_x1, size_t size_y1, size_t size_x2, size_t size_y2>
void product(int (&arr)[size_x1][size_y1],int (&arr1)[size_x2][size_y2]);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/eaov8jxM1)

Comment: If the OP is trying to define matrix multiplication, then three dimentions suffice: `size_x, size_xy, size_y`. The inputs  being `arr1[size_x][size_xy], arr2[size_xy][size_y]` resulting in `arr3[size_x][size_y]` as the the outcome.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with C++20 you can use `auto` as type for function parameters:

```
void product(auto &arr, auto &arr1)
```

You can get the array sizes with `std::size(arr)` for the first index and `std::size(*arr)` for the second index.

Complete program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void product(auto &arr, auto &arr1)
{
   for (const auto &inner: arr)
   for (const auto &elem: inner)
   {
     cout << "arr[][] is " << elem << endl;
   }


   for (const auto &inner: arr1)
   for (const auto &elem: inner)
   {
     cout << "arr1[][] is " << elem << endl;
   }

   cout << "size of arr " << size(arr) << " * " << size(*arr) << endl;
   cout << "size of arr " << size(arr1) << " * " << size(*arr1) << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int A[2][2] = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }};
    int B[3][1] = { { 0}, { 6 }, {3} };

    product(A,B);
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/7a315erhf